# TFS Rest API - Abandon Pull request

Tags: rest, powershell, tfs

I want to abandon a pull request in TFS using the REST API.

I have TFS 2018, using PowerShell 5.1 to access the REST api via the Invoke-RestMethod function. I can GET all sorts of information, and can POST to create a new PR, but I can't update an existing PR.

I call `https://<tfs_url>/<ProjectCollection>/<project>/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=3.0` and get a list of all repositories in the project.

I filter in Powershell to the repository I want, and I take the Id property of the JSON payload pass that into a GET request: 
`https://<tfs_url>/<ProjectCollection>/<project>/_apis/git/repositories/4c2a4916-27bf-40f2-bb32-00e4a20d44e8/PullRequests?api-version=3.0`

This returns all (or at least all active) pull requests, which I filter in Powershell to the PR with the source/target refs which gives me a object with the PullRequestID and a bunch of other info. 
[image]
The PR ID matches when I view it in the web gui
[image]

Now I try to update the status (or other property) of the PR by following the [MS documentation and examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/git/pull%20requests/update?view=vsts-rest-5.0&WT.mc_id=email)
My PS code:

```
$requestBody = @"
{
   "status" = "abandoned"
}
"@
$fullURL = https://<tfs_url>/<ProjectCollection>/<project>/_apis/git/repositories/4c2a4916-27bf-40f2-bb32-00e4a20d44e8/pullrequests/2418?api-version=3.0
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -UseDefaultCredentials -uri $fullURL -Method Patch -Body $requestBody -ContentType application/json-patch+json
```

Which returns a generic error: `The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.`

So then I tested my requests in Chrome using Restlet Client, and I get a better error with the same url/body/content type: `"Invalid argument value.\r\nParameter name: The pull request to update was not valid."`

I tried using the PR title instead of the ID, tried several different IDs from the response I got when I GET the PR info. 
I have tried creating a Personal Access Token and using a basic authentication header following [Marcus Felling's blog post](https://www.marcusfelling.com/blog/2017/create-vsts-pull-request-via-vsts-rest-api/)
I have tried calling the Invoke-RestMethod function using both 'application/json' and 'application/json-patch+json' content types with the same result.

I have also tried using a different API version (4.1, all requests I use with 5.0 or 5.0-preview.1 fail) 
I also tried adding a `artifactId` property to my body because the documentation mentions that it uniquely identifies the pull request. (I have found no examples that show this property being used, and I get the same error in Restlet Client indicating that the Pull Request to update was not valid)

The documentation shows the same url structure that I am using with version 4.1, and I can't even run the simple requests that just update the description or title, so this seems to be an issue with my URL and not the body of my request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your request body has an equal sign (=) sign, rather than a colon (:).

```
$requestBody = @"
{
   "status": "abandoned"
}
"@
```

Not 100% sure this solves your actual problem, but I'm guessing it might be related?

Comment: Thank you! that solved the problem! I was looking in all the wrong places and totally overlooked that!